# Handling the closing of App By Android

Tags: java, android, memory-management, service, android-asynctask

I have created an App which requires to run a operation in background for quite some time suppose 10 - 15 mins.

I am running this operation in An AsyncTask. So during this time the user is minimizing the Screen and using his other apps in his phone as usual.

When this operation is started I am creating a Progress Dialog box and then keep updating it regularly.

But this is the error which I am receiving sometimes very rarely once the operation is over

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
View=DecorView@1234567[ABC:] not attached to window manager PackageName
```

And this is the detailed stack log

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>        View=DecorView@1234567[ABC:] not attached to window manager PackageName
>
> ```
>     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:508)
>
>     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:417)
>
>     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:136)
>
>     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:446)
>
>     at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:429)
>
>     at android.app.Dialog.cancel(Dialog.java:1353)
>
>     at PACKAGENAME
>
>     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:6078)
>
>     at PACKAGENAME
>
>     at PACKAGENAME
>
>     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:667)
>
>     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:684)
>
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6823)
>
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1557)
>
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
> ```

**To my knowledge this error is because the Android OS wanted to release some memory hence my App was closed since this was not visible to the user. But is there any way to tackle this thing?**

Any help would be really appreciated.

EDIT: This is the code which I am using

```
 public class load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
          for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
            PerformSomeOperation();
            UpdateTheProgress();
          }         
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void n) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mProgressDialog.cancel();
                        CreateAnotherDialog();//This dialog is created to show the user completion of the progress.
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: You should create a FOREGROUND service that will perform the task to ensure it's not killed by the system.

Comment: @Pawel Thans for the answer. Suppose the service is not killed but is it possible for the activity to be killed by the Android OS?

Comment: Please show the relevant code.

Comment: @Anatolii Will shortly update with the code.

Comment: @Anatolii Have updated the question with the code. Can you please have a look.

Comment: Simple, don't update the UI elements if the activity has been killed.

Comment: @I_of_T But I have to show the result of the loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this crash because you're trying to update the UI when it's in the background so your `Activity` could be destroyed at that point. By the way, `onPostExecute` runs your code on the main thread already but as you're sending a separate message to the main looper you're postponing your logic a bit which can also cause a problem. Moreover, But the main question - why to update the UI if it's not visible to the user anyways?

Also, because you're using the `AsyncTask` as an inner class you may leak (though temporarily) your `Activity` object as it's referenced implicitly by the task.

From [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask):

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds
>   at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of
>   time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by
>   the java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor
>   and FutureTask.

So, don't use AsyncTasks for long-running operations. A better approach would be to use:

1. `IntentService` together with `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate with your `Activity` / `Fragment` (in `API >= 26` you should use `JobIntentService` as `IntentService` may misbehave due to new restrictions on background services).
2. `RxAndroid` (or just `ExecutorService`/`Thread`) together with `Architecture-Components` (more specifically with `LiveData`) - this way a result of your task can be cached or it can survive the config change.

My personal favourite is option 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How is it possible to save/cache a ArrayList. Also Is it possible to run two Intent Service at the same time?

Comment: Your answer is very detailed and helpful. Thanks once again

Comment: @RajeshK You're welcome. 1) To save your ArrayList where? If you're talking about sending it from your Service to Activity then you can do this by using Intent' and putting it into Serializable (putSerializable() method)  2) It's possible to run several IntentServices in parallel. 2)

Comment: Can you please help to answer this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508046/binding-a-jobintentservice-to-a-activity

Answer (score 1):

There are few things to say: (1) the "onPostExecuted()"  method is already executed on the UiThread/MainThread, so "runOnUiThread()" is not required. (2) if the Activity is minimized/destroyed when the Asynctask reach the final pass you get an Exception. So you have to check if the View is attached using "View. IsAttachedToWindow()" before execute some GUI methods like "mProgressDialog.cancel()". (3) you have to create a Thread or a Service to do a task that should run/work more than few seconds, or the System could kill it at anytime.

Comment: Thanks for the points.1)  But many time I had received a error on `onPostExecuted()` hence I use `runOnUiThread()` always. 3) Suppose if I create a service to run the operation, but will the activity be destroyed?

Comment: The Service or Thread runs even if the Activity is destroyed exactly as an Asynctask does. A Service can be automatically restarted by the System if the STICKY flag is used on it, and however a Sticky Service is one of the latest thing killed by the System if Memory is required, so the kill procedure is very rare to occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But @Anatolii  seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Sorry for that but his answer is more detailed for me to understand and provides a complete solution. Sorry once again.